# Access violation after reallocating memory

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I get access violation if I'm allocating memory to `list->v[list->length]`

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char* denumire, * producator;
    int cantitate;
}produs;
typedef struct {
    produs** v;
    int lungime;
    int capacitate;
} Lista;

produs crearePr(char* nume, char* producator, int cantitate)
{
    produs material;   
    material.denumire = (char*)malloc(strlen(nume) + 1);
    strcpy(material.denumire, nume);
    material.producator = (char*)malloc(strlen(producator) + 1);
    strcpy(material.producator, producator);
    material.cantitate = cantitate;
    return material;
}

void creareLi(Lista* lista)
{
    lista->lungime = 0;
    lista->capacitate = 1;
    lista->v = (produs**)malloc(sizeof(produs*) * lista->capacitate);
}

void redim(Lista *l)
{
    l->capacitate *= 2;
    l->v = (produs**)realloc(l->v,sizeof(produs) * l->capacitate);
}

void adauga(Lista *lista, produs p)
{
    if (lista->lungime == lista->capacitate) redim(&lista);
    
    lista->v[lista->lungime] = (produs*)malloc(sizeof(produs));
    *lista->v[lista->lungime] = p;
    lista->lungime++;

}

int main()
{
    Lista lista;
    creareLi(&lista);
    adauga(&lista, crearePr("Zahar", "Tarom", 100));
    return 0;
}
```

Explanation:

- `crearePr` should create a `struct produs`
- `creareLi` should initialize the list, set capacity 1 and length 0
- `redim` is called to expand the capacity
- `adauga` should add `struct produs` to list

Comment: The library headers show this is not C code but C++.

Comment: @WeatherVane -- sort of, but nothing from the iostream library is used in the code. The code itself is raw C.

Comment: Please make up your mind. Post the actual code that you are using.

Comment: @PeteBecker a C compiler would not have accepted those C++ library headers. And a C++ compiler is not C.

Comment: `if (lista->lungime == lista->capacitate) redim(&lista);` is incorrect. `lista` is already a pointer, pass it as-is.

Comment: @WeatherVane — aside from the incorrect `#include` directives (which have now been edited out) the code is raw C, and questions about why it fails are questions about C, not C++.

Comment: There is a problem in `redim`, `sizeof(produs)` is used to calculate allocation size instead of `sizeof(produs*)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enable warnings in your compiler, you'll see something like this:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of 'redim' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   41 |     if (lista->lungime == lista->capacitate) redim(&lista);
      |                                                    ^~~~~~
      |                                                    |
      |                                                    Lista **
```

That's telling you something very important. What you have right now causes undefined behavior.

The variable `lista` is a pointer to the location of your data in memory. You are reinterpreting `&redis` as that pointer, but now the `redis` function is going to modify memory where the `lista` pointer was stored, instead of what it was pointing at.

This will result in some form of memory corruption, as your struct is larger than a pointer and you're writing into uncharted territory.

Changing the call to `redim(lista)` will fix this problem.

Comment: It worked but there one more problem, i'm using all this functions in 2 different headers and i still get that memory access violation. If im using just 1 file is working perfectly

Comment: My crystal ball says you defined your list as a global variable in a header without declaring it `extern`. If you can't resolve the problem, then it's time to write a new question.